# How to stop Razors automatic encode of \n?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some strings that contains `\n`, Like for example:

```
ViewBag.stringTest = "Hello\nWorld!\nBreakrow";
```

That I want to use in my view and more specific in my javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var howItShouldBe = "Hello\nWorld!\nBreakrow";

   var stringTest1 = "@ViewBag.stringTest";
   var stringTest2 = "@Html.Encode(ViewBag.stringTest)";
   var stringTest3 = "@(new HtmlString(ViewBag.stringTest))";
   var stringTest4 = "@Html.Raw(ViewBag.stringTest)";
   var stringTest5 = "@MvcHtmlString.Create(ViewBag.stringTest)";
   var stringTest6 = "@ViewBag.stringTest.ToString()";
});
```

However when using @ razor it replaces the \n with actual breakrows/linebreaks(Like it *kinda* should) But in my case it breaks the javascript and I want it to actually display the \n instead of doing the linebreak.

Is there anyway of preventing this? usually @Html.Raw is enough for most stuff but not for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
"@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(s.Name))"
```

It uses [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.javascriptstringencode(v=vs.110).aspx), which should convert `CR` to `\r`, `LF` to `\n` and `TAB` to `\t`

Comment: Yeah this works great. However it does not convert it to \t (or what you meant by that) it displays \n just without the linebreak happening like : "Hello\nWorld!\nBreakrow"

Comment: @HenrikP: Isn't that exactly what you need? The `\t` is for tabs, which shouldn't show up in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I misread, I thought you meant all of them would get converted to \t. But now I see you only meant TAB. But yes this is what I wanted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I suppose the \n is replaced with linebreaks at the moment you declare the string constant. Try to add @ like this:

```
ViewBag.stringTest = @"Hello\nWorld!\nBreakrow";
```